# Cannot login to mariadb from user account. ERROR 1045 (28000)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-administration

I created one `myaccount` with a password and used :
`select user,password,host,plugin from mysql.user;`

```
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| user                | password                                  | host      | plugin      |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| root                | *84BB5DF4823DA319BBF86C99624479A198E6EEE9 | localhost | unix_socket |
| myaccount@localhost | *28F1DE8C4229B1D4F62F752EA3812747CE4E5CA0 | %         |             |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

As you can see, there is no `plugin` configured for `myaccount`. I was expecting this would mean that I'd be allowed to access the mariadb with my password, but when logging from my account which is called `libra` and not `myaccount` I get a :

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myaccount'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

How can I set the `plugin` attribute to allow password authentication from any account? `myaccount` doesn't exist as a user on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an auth plugin issue.

There's no account named `'myaccount'@'localhost'` on your database. There *is* an account named `'myaccount@localhost'@'%'`, however. Yeah, that name is strange. Yeah, the way one creates accounts on MariaDB / MySQL is strange.

Try this:

```
CREATE USER 'myaccount'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'REDACTED';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myaccount'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'myaccount'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'REDACTED';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myaccount'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

That will set you up to log in both from localhost and any other host, to accounts with administrative privileges on the server. That requires, on MariaDB / MySQL, two accounts. Sigh. (If you don't want administrative privileges, change the `GRANT` statements.)

And, of course, replace `REDACTED` with the password you want.

Comment: OMG `mysql -u myaccount@localhost -p` did it! This is so weird I. So is my account called `myaccount@localhost` and not `myaccount`?